# Encoding errors in embedded Json file

Tags: c#, encoding

I have run into an issue and can't quite get my head around it.

I have this code:

```
    public List<NavigationModul> LoadNavigation()
    {
        byte[] navBytes = NavigationResources.Navigation;
        var encoding = GetEncoding(navBytes);            
        string json = encoding.GetString(navBytes);
        List<NavigationModul> navigation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NavigationModul>>(json);
        return navigation;
    }

    public static Encoding GetEncoding(byte [] textBytes)
    {
       if (textBytes[0] == 0x2b && textBytes[1] == 0x2f && textBytes[2] == 0x76) return Encoding.UTF7;
        if (textBytes[0] == 0xef && textBytes[1] == 0xbb && textBytes[2] == 0xbf) return Encoding.UTF8;
        if (textBytes[0] == 0xff && textBytes[1] == 0xfe) return Encoding.Unicode; //UTF-16LE
        if (textBytes[0] == 0xfe && textBytes[1] == 0xff) return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode; //UTF-16BE
        if (textBytes[0] == 0 && textBytes[1] == 0 && textBytes[2] == 0xfe && textBytes[3] == 0xff) return Encoding.UTF32;
        return Encoding.ASCII;
    }
```

The Goal is to load an embedded Json File (NavigationResources.Navigation) from a ResourceFile. The Navigation File is an embedded file. We are just jusing the ResourceManager to avoid Magic strings.

After loading the bytes of the embedded file and checking for its encoding, I now read the String from the file and pass it to the JsonConverter.DeserializeObject function.

But unfortunaly this fails due to invalid Json. Long story short: The loaded json string still contains encoding identification bytes. And I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

I also tryed to convert the utf8 bytearray to default encoding before loading the string but this only makes the encoding bytes become a visible charecter.

I talked to my peers and they told me that they have run into the same problem reading embedded batchfiles, leading to broken batchfiles. They didn't know how to fix the problem either, but came up with a workaround for the batchfiles itself (add a blank line into the batchfile to make it work)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I would strongly advise you to just use UTF-8 for *all* your embedded text files. You control them, after all... don't make life hard for yourself.

Comment: they are UFT-8 the check is just to make sure it still is the correct encoding when loading its content.

Comment: If you identify the BOM you know its total length so know how many lead bytes to ignore, .Skip/.ToArray or BlockCopy a new array that does not contain them.

Comment: Personally, I simply wouldn't do this. If you know they're all meant to be UTF-8, then just load them as UTF-8. Write unit tests to validate that they *are* UTF-8, but don't try to detect something that *should* always give the same answer.

Comment: @Jon, the problem still occurs if you load them as utf8. Ecoding.Utf8.GetString(filebytes) still leaves BOM bytes in the content instead of removing them.
removing them before using GetString solves this issue.

Comment: @ChristianJäger: If the problem is really just that `Encoding.GetString` doesn't remove the BOM, then I'd have posted it as a question without a) encoding identification; b) JSON parsing; c) loading the data from resources. A [mcve] would just have consisted of a hard-coded set of bytes, then a call to `Encoding.GetString`, and the results. That would have been a clearer question, without extraneous parts. Just feedback for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alex K. I have a solution:

Cuting of the Identification Bytes before calling Encoding.GetString did the trick.

Here is my function I now use to do the Task:

```
    public static string GetStringFromEncodedBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
        int skipBytes = 0;
        if (bytes[0] == 0x2b && bytes[1] == 0x2f && bytes[2] == 0x76) {
            encoding = Encoding.UTF7;
            skipBytes = 3;
        }
        if (bytes[0] == 0xef && bytes[1] == 0xbb && bytes[2] == 0xbf)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            skipBytes = 3;
        }

        if (bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xfe)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            skipBytes = 2;
        }

        if (bytes[0] == 0xfe && bytes[1] == 0xff)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
            skipBytes = 2;
        }
        if (bytes[0] == 0 && bytes[1] == 0 && bytes[2] == 0xfe && bytes[3] == 0xff)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.UTF32;
            skipBytes = 4;
        }

        return encoding.GetString(bytes.Skip(skipBytes).ToArray());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach, removing the BOM *after* decoding:

```
// Your data is always in UTF-8 apparently, so just rely on that.
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
if (text.StartsWith("\ufeff"))
{
    text = text.Substring(1);
}
```

This has the downside of copying the string, of course.

Or if you *do* want to skip the bytes:

```
// Again, we're assuming UTF-8
int start = data.Length >= 3 && data[0] == 0xef &&
            data[1] == 0xbb && data[2] == 0xbf)
            ? 3 : 0;
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, start, data.Length - start);
```

That way you don't need to use `Skip` and `ToArray`, and it avoids doing any extraneous copying.

Comment: Yes, I agree, your solution is more simple, but It will lack the possibility to support other encoding formats in the future. I made Alex K's solution an extensionmethod to Encoding in our Project, to support all types of encodings in the future. I know it violates the YAGNI principle but I will just leave it the way it is. Thanks to all wo participated

Comment: @ChristianJäger: Do you have concrete reasons to think you'll even *need* to support further encodings? Note that not all UTF-8 files will have a BOM - it's quite uncommon outside Windows, in my understanding. Assuming ASCII (or *far worse* `Encoding.Default` as per the currently accepted answer) for anything that doesn't have a BOM is a really bad idea, IMO. Given that these are resources where you *control* the data, why would you not just make them all UTF-8?

Comment: Our application also supports users to upload specific files into the sytem, those files have to be parsed as well. So we do NOT have full control over the encoding.

Comment: @ChristianJäger: Then you should not just rely on a BOM either - and you *certainly* shouldn't use `Encoding.Default`. You should separate the concerns here: 1) Detecting/requesting the encoding; 2) Removing any BOM which is present. Those are two orthogonal questions, IMO. I believe the solutions I've given here are the cleanest way of removing any BOM which is present. Note that the string approach will work regardless of the encoding, as the BOM will simply be the first character.